# MySQL to Excel charset issue

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export, mysqli

I have a database set up which accepts user registrations and their details etc. I'm looking to export the database to an excel file using php.

The problem I am having is that some of the entrants have entered foreign characters in, such as Turkish, which has been written into the database 'incorrectly' - as far as I have ascertained, the charset was likely set up incorrectly when it was first made.

I have made my code to export the database into excel (below) but I cannot get the Excel document to show correctly regardless of how I try to encode the data

```
<?php 

require_once('../php/db.php');

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Download.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$query =    "SELECT * FROM users";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($result) {
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
        $header .= $field->name."\t";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $line = '';
            foreach($row as $value) {
                if((!isset($value)) OR ($value == "")) {
                    $value = "\t";
                } else {
                    $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
                    $value = '"'.$value.'"'."\t";
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $data .= trim($line)."\n";
        }
        $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);
        if($data == "") {
            $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
        }
    }
    print mb_convert_encoding("$header\n$data", 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
} else die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

When I do this it comes up with an error when opening it up saying that Excel doesn't recognise the file type, it opens the document but its drawn boxes around all the Turkish characters its tried to write.

I'm no PHP expert this is just information I've kind of pieced together.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Much appreciated

Moz

Comment: Well, if it's already messed up in the database, you should probably try to fix it *there* before adding Excel files into the mix (if it's indeed possible to recover the data - some charset conversions are destructive and the original may not be recoverable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you appear to be creating a tab-delimited text file and then returning it to the browser with the MIME-type `application/octet-stream` and the file extension `.xls`.  Excel might work out that's tab-delimited (but it sounds from your error as though it doesn't), but in any case you really should use the `text/tab-separated-values` MIME type and `.txt` file extension so that everything knows exactly what the data is.
2. Secondly, to create tab-delimited files, you'd be very wise to export the data directly from MySQL (using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html)), as all manner of pain can arise with escaping delimiters and such when you try to cook it yourself.  For example:

   ```
    SELECT * FROM users INTO OUFILE '/tmp/users.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   ```

Then you would merely need to read the contents of that file to the browser using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

If you absolutely *must* create the delimited file from within PHP, consider using its [`fputscsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function (you can still specify that you wish to use a tab-delimiter).

3. Always use the `.txt` file extension rather than `.csv` *even if your file is comma-separated* as some versions of Excel assume that *all* files with the `.csv` extension are encoded using `Windows-1252`.
4. As far as character encodings go, you will need to inspect the contents of your database to determine whether data is stored correctly or not: the best way to do this is to `SELECT HEX(column) ...` in order that you can inspect the underlying bytes.  Once that has been determined, you can `UPDATE` the records if conversions are required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried changing the MIME type and giving it a .txt extension, except I was still getting the incorrect versions of the characters. I'll try using the 'INTO OUTFILE' method once I read up on it a little more. At the moment I think my problem lies within the data in the database, it's saved under collation 'latin1_swedish_ci' (the db was not set up by me) which is probably why I'm getting the data messed up. I will try editing the records and try from there

Comment: @AndrewMorris: The collation doesn't affect how anything is stored, merely how comparisons are undertaken.  However, for the `latin1_swedish_ci` collation to be valid, the data *must* be stored in the `latin1` (i.e. Windows-1252) encoding, which has quite a limited character set; you may well find that your Turkish characters cannot be represented in that character set and have been permanently lost, in which case the data will need to be reinserted/updated in a more appropriate character set (I'd suggest using UTF-8).

Comment: I don't think the data has been destroyed or has lost the original characters, If I print the values from the database using the code I gave in the first instance (just print it to the page rather than export to a database) all the characters are correct, but I think I probably will have to reinsert the data, even though there are about 1000 records

Comment: @AndrewMorris: If no information has been lost, then you won't need to reinsert anything; at worst, you'll just need to perform some character set conversions, which you can do entirely in SQL.  But you'll need to first understand how the data is stored in order to determine what conversions (if any) are necessary.

Comment: I'm getting closer, I just read through [this page](http://nicj.net/2011/04/17/mysql-converting-an-incorrect-latin1-column-to-utf8) to try to understand how the data is being viewed at the moment, I duplicated my table to test it on, and as far as I can tell it has worked, the database itself is now showing the correct information, however when outputting it, i'm getting '?' for certain letters, however I think combining this with the help you gave before might get me the final result.